# the arrow '->' separator is crashing when calling function from class

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, function-pointers

I'm working on a project for class and I'm using classes and pointers of type class to call some functions in the class but it's crashing on Code Blocks and Eclipse and I don't know what is going on 
Note it crashes when assigning x with y

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class a{
private:
    int x;
public:
    void set_X(int y){
        x=y;
    }
};

int main()
{
    a *Ptr;
    Ptr->set_X(5);
}
```

Comment: Are there any errors or messages from log files? If yes, please edit your question!

Comment: Pointer "Ptr" is uninitialized and thus do not point to anywhere meaningful. You should construct an instance of class a and make Ptr point to that instance. Only then should you call set_X on that instance of class a, using the pointer Ptr.

Comment: You can't use the value of a variable until you assign that variable a value. You never assign `Ptr` a value before you use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> a *Ptr;
> Ptr->set_X(5);
> ```

Your `Ptr` does not point to anything. Trying to invoke a member function on an uninitialised pointer results in **undefined behaviour**. Crashing is just one of the many more or less random things that can happen.

Luckily, in your example, you do not need a pointer anyway. You can simply write:

```
a my_a;
my_a.set_X(5);
```

Pointers often point to dynamically allocated objects. If this is what you want, you must use `new` and `delete` accordingly:

```
a *Ptr = new a;
Ptr->set_X(5);
delete Ptr;
```

In modern C++, `std::unique_ptr` is typically a superior alternative because you don't have to manually release the allocated memory, which removes a lot of potential programming errors:

```
auto Ptr = std::make_unique<a>();
Ptr->set_X(5);
// no delete necessary
```

Answer (score 1):

Basic rule:  creating a pointer (a variable that contains the address of an object, or otherwise is `NULL` (or `nullptr` since 2011)) as pointed out by Christian Hackl in comments) does not create a corresponding pointee (an object who's address can be stored in the pointer).

More formally, `Ptr` is an uninitialised pointer.  Even accessing its value gives undefined behaviour (e.g.  `some_other_pointer = Ptr`).    For operator `->` to work correctly, the pointer must first be initialised so it points at a valid object.

```
 a aobj;
 a *Ptr = &aobj;
 Ptr->set_X(42);   // OK

 a *Ptr2 = new a;
 Ptr2->set_X(42);    // OK
 delete Ptr2;
```

Comment: *"a variable that contains the address of an object"* - ... or is `nullptr`

Answer (score -1):

You have just declared a pointer variable of type `a*` but it doesn't point to a valid memory address. And since you are calling a member function via that pointer which updates a data-member hence you have segfault because `this` pointer is `NULL`.

You must initialize pointer with some valid memory address of class `a` object.

Following can be done,

```
a* ptr = new a;
ptr->set_X(5);
// ...
delete ptr;
```

In this case. It would be better that you should use some smart_ptr like `std::shared_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr` so that you don't need to worry about releasing resources manually.

Or

```
   a* ptr;
   a aobj_;
   ptr = &aobj_;
   ptr->set_X(5);
```

Comment: And `delete` it later of course, or better yet, use a [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr).

Comment: Then you should add it to your answer. At the moment it offers a correct solution, but one that is likely to lead to harder-to-spot errors later.